# Trying to scrape images from reddit, having trouble cleaning up strings

Tags: php, json, screen-scraping

So I'm not asking for you to fix my script, if you know the answer I would appreciate it if you just pointed me in the right direction. This is a script I found and I'm trying to edit it for a project.

I believe that whats going on is the formatting of $reddit is causing problems when I input that string into $url. I am not sure how to filter the string.

Right after I posted this I had the idea of using concatenation on $reddit to get the desired result instead of filtering the string. Not sure.

Thanks!

**picgrabber.php**

```
include("RIS.php");

$reddit = "pics/top/?sort=top&t=all";

$pages = 5;

$t = new RIS($reddit, $pages);

$t->getImagesOnPage();

$t->saveImage();
```

**RIS.php**

```
class RIS {

var $after = "";
var $reddit = "";


public function __construct($reddit, $pages) {


    $this->reddit = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '' , $reddit);

    if(!file_exists($this->reddit)) {
        mkdir($this->reddit, 0755);
    }

    $pCounter = 1;
    while($pCounter <= $pages) {
        $url = "http://reddit.com/r/$reddit/.json?limit=100&after=$this->after";
        $this->getImagesOnPage($url);
        $pCounter++;
    }

}


private function getImagesOnPage($url) {

    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $js = json_decode($json);

    foreach($js->data->children as $n) {
        if(preg_match('(jpg$|gif$|png$)', $n->data->url, $match)) {
            echo $n->data->url."\n";
            $this->saveImage($n->data->url);
        }

        $this->after = $js->data->after;
    }
}


private function saveImage($url) {
    $imgName = explode("/", $url);
    $img = file_get_contents($url);

    //if the file doesnt already exist...
    if(!file_exists($this->reddit."/".$imgName[(count($imgName)-1)])) {
        file_put_contents($this->reddit."/".$imgName[(count($imgName)-1)], $img);
    }
  }
}
```

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\RIS.php on line 33

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\RIS.php on line 33

Fatal error: Call to private method RIS::getImagesOnPage() from context '' in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\vollyeballgrabber.php on line 23

**line 33:**

```
       foreach($js->data->children as $n) {


        var_dump($url);
```

**returns:**

```
string(78) "http://reddit.com/r/pics/top/?sort=top&t=all/.json?limit=100&after=" NULL
```

Comment: Which one is line 33 ?

Comment: Can you `var_dump()` all variables before the `foreach`; `$url`, `$json` and `$js`?

Comment: When I var_dump() one of the three it takes me directly to the url, any suggestions?

Comment: That url does not return json but an html page.

Comment: I don't know enough about json to know whats going on here.

Comment: It's not json, so you can't treat it like json. You could use an xml parser: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

Answer (score 0):

$reddit in picgrabber.php has GET parameters

In the class RIS, you're embedding that value into a string that has another GET set in it with the ".json" token between.

The resulting url is:
 http://reddit.com/r/pics/top/?sort=top&t=all/.json?limit=100&after=

The ".json" token needs to come after the end of the location portion of the url and before the GET sets. I would also change any addition "?" tokens to "&" (ampersands) so any additional sets of GET parameters you decide to concatenate to the URL string become additional parameters.

Like this:
 http://reddit.com/r/pics/top/.json?sort=top&t=all&limit=100&after=

The difference is, your url is returning html code because the reddit server doesn't understand how to parse what you're sending. You're trying to parse html with a json decoder. My URL returns actual json data. That should get your json decoder returning an actual json object array.